# how to connect to a remote computer without credentials?

Tags: powershell, credentials, remoting, powershell-remoting

i am already done from writing a Powershell script to get some info from other computers in a domain .
it looks somehow weird, but is it possible to run this script test.ps1 on the remote machine without entering the (Credential)
cause it seems to be illogical to run :

`enable-psremoting -Force`

on every machine , then :

`Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\path\test.ps1 -ComputerName computername -Credential domain\usrname`

I look forward to your answers

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way around this.

Your admins should use Global Policy to enable remoting for all desired computers in your company.

You could use sysinternals psexec to run powershell remotely otherwise:

```
 psexec \\remote-computer powershell -File <....> 
 psexec \\remote-computer powershell -Command <....>
```

For `-File` variant to work file must be available on remote server OR accessible via SMB share.

Note that this requires you to be admin on remote machine as it uses your windows credentials. You can specify remote user and password otherwise.

You can also

```
 psexec \\remote-computer powershell -Command "enable-psremoting -Force"
```

In order not to run this every time you could automate it via for instance proxy function to Invoke-Command by adding a parameter to it to for instance `EnableRemoting` and then you would be able to call it such as:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\path\test.ps1 -ComputerName computername -EnableRemoting
```

In proxy you could set this parameter to be true by default in which case you don't need it. Apart from proxy you could also use a function for this.

Before doing this, you will speed things up if you first test if it is already enabled:

```
if (!(Test-WsMan \\remote)) { psexec .... enable-psremoting... }
Invoke-Command ...
```

Comment: but we still have the problem of username and password.

Comment: That uses your domain username and password *implicitly*. You can't access OS without one. You can always use default admin account